# Why getters and setters in Backbone's models?

Tags: backbone.js

Why are there getters and setters with Backbone models? There are no private/protected attributes, so the getters and setters are a bit useless for encapsulation. I know they are useful for the  validations, but other than that, what are their utility if we can bypass them?

Comment: Did you just answer your question? :)

Comment: "Making attributes `private`" is not the same as "encapsulation". Encapsulation means hiding how a logical property is actually stored from the point of view of the caller.

Comment: @alex I'm just wondering if the validation is the only reason why there are getters and setters :/.

Comment: @millimoose Encapsulation is the reason why there are getters and setters.

Comment: @Maxwell Yes. My point is that getters and setters, and thus encapsulation, makes sense even if you can't make fields / attributes private. (For instance, if you want a property that isn't actually backed by an attribute, like in the canonical example of the circumference of a `Circle` object computed from its radius, although that doesn't apply to Backbone.) In Backbone, mainly it seems useful for tracking changes and emitting change events.

Comment: @millimoose I see. But it's not really hiding the property if it's always public and accessible without it's getter and setter.

Comment: @Maxwell That's just an artifact of using Javascript as the underlying language. Encapsulation is a property of a *design* - in this case, of the design of Backbone's model layer. If you're bypassing the getters and setters you're using the library wrong and probably introducing bugs.

Comment: How do you propose to trigger `'change'` events without calling `set`? Events are sort of important in Backbone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`set` is not simply doing below thing.

```
this.attributes["key"] = value;
```

If you bypass it, you will miss all other functions that it is doing [here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-40).

Currently it is doing 2 functionalities.

1.It is calling `_validate` method before value is assigned to attributes. [refer this](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate).

2.It triggers `change` event if you listen for an attribute change.

If they add further functionalities in future, you may lose them, if you by-pass `set`.