# backbone sync passes wrong parameters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model

It's a pretty simple trick that I thought should work fine however it doesn't. So I have multiple checkboxes on the page. And whenever they are changed I would like to record any change to the database. So in the view event 'click' on checkbox I have similar to this:

```
var filter_name = $(e.target).attr("name");
var filter_value = $( "input:checkbox[name=" + filter_name + "]:checked" ).map(function () {
        return this.value;
}).get();


console.log("filter_name: " + filter_name); #=> my_method_name

CarInsuranceApp.aciq.set({filter_name: filter_value});
CarInsuranceApp.aciq.save();
```

And here the results that I receive as a JSON:

```
"filter_name"=>"extra"
```

So my question would be how to dynamically pass model attribute name on the set?

Comment: why are you using map function to get filter value? do you want that as array?

Answer (score 2):

use like this.

```
CarInsuranceApp.aciq.set(filter_name, filter_value);
```

Comment: Was using $.map for getting results from a check_boxes with similar name attribute

Answer (score -1):

Here is a possible one line JavaScript`ish solution:

```
CarInsuranceApp.aciq.attributes[filter_name] = filter_name;
```

Comment: avoid using like this. assign values using `set`.

Comment: Why? Any explanations?

Comment: see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393858/why-getters-and-setters-in-backbones-models/19397097#19397097